# Ajax Error in Shiny DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, r, shiny

I've encountered quite an unusual problem, I think. After installing the new shiny version Shiny v0.10.2.1 via CRAN my datatables no longer worked (I've attached an example) in combination with a notification that I've encountered an Ajax Error. After reinstalling 0.10.2 it worked again.

```
    output$IntTable<-renderDataTable(

  {if (input$intthresbutton == 0)

    return("")


  RunModules_InternalSeverityCalibration_Progress(session)

#Sortierung Ergebnisse Interne Kalibrierung

  keep<-c("internalThreshold")

  IntResult<-GlobalResult$InternalSeverityCalibration[keep,,drop=FALSE]

  IntProzente<-paste(round(as.numeric(GlobalResult$InternalSeverityCalibration["internalBodyProbability",]),2),"%",sep="")

  IntResult3<-rbind(IntResult,IntProzente)

  RowNames<-c("Interne Grenze","Interne Body Wahrscheinlichkeit")

  IntResult2<-cbind(RowNames,IntResult3) 

  colnames(IntResult2)<-c("","CC","EP","IB", "FM", "FE")
  ##printing of results of calibration

  IntResult2
  }

, options = list(bSortClasses = TRUE, bFilter = FALSE,bPaginate = FALSE))
```

Has anybody encountered the same problem?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: I spent the whole day updating my dashboard. Some of the things were simple (Converting from Hungarian to CamelCase https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert others were not. Maybe you have dependencies on other libraries that might be incomparable with new version of Shiny like ShinyIncubator? Or maybe its just the old style of datatables?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea, but the upgrade is already implemented in  0.10.2, and it works there...

I have shinySky as well as ShinyIncubator, but I don't either for my datatables.